# Eclipse closing all hours

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Ubuntu version 13.04.

Eclipse Juno

And

java-7-openjdk-amd64

After that I make,  one "debug" he it closes, I open , it loads and closes when it opens again, every time I try to "debug" it does so. Will a hardware problem?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc6e05396d5, pid=5236, tid=140494709798656
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b15
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0+0x4246d5]  webkitWebViewRegisterForIconNotification+0xb5
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fc770009800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5237, stack(0x00007fc779353000,0x00007fc779454000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000001c1c

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007fc77037ba10, RCX=0x00007fc764afeb00, RDX=0x00007fc77037ba10
RSP=0x00007fc779451218, RBP=0x00007fc770e1f0c0, RSI=0x00007fc6e0512180, RDI=0x0000000000001bac
R8 =0x00007fc7702ce530, R9 =0x0000000000000020, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000028
R12=0x00007fc764dafa00, R13=0x00007fc7702f0120, R14=0x00007fc77026f7b0, R15=0x00007fc770e1f0c0
RIP=0x00007fc6e05396d5, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fc779451218)
0x00007fc779451218:   00007fc6e0512108 0000000000000001
0x00007fc779451228:   0000000000000004 00007fc770e1f0c0
0x00007fc779451238:   00007fc6e0512189 0000000000000004
0x00007fc779451248:   00007fc764afeb1b 00007fc764dafa00
0x00007fc779451258:   0000000000000004 00007fc7703aba80

...
```

And to configuration for eclipse ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Maybe circumventing the problem by changing the browser in `Window > Preferences, General > Web Browser` helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error occurs in `libwebkitgtk`, it should be related to a browser view within Eclipse, such as the Javadoc view. You could try to update the library in question using your package maneger. You could also try to close the view.

The bug could be in the native library or in the JVM's bridge code which uses the library.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug related to Eclipse and Webkit. ([Eclipse Official Bug Database](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400626))

One workaround is tell Eclipse to not use Webkit and use Mozilla's Gecko instead.

Add these two lines at the end of your eclipse.ini:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/lib/xulrunner
```

This workaround, by default, greately reduces the features of JavaDoc hover view.
The lost features can be restored by installing a library called "XULRunner".
According to [SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux), the latest version of XULRunner that Eclipse 4.x can use is 10.x. We can obtain it from [Mozilla's FTP site](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/10.0/runtimes/).

The following commands will download and unpack the 64bit build of XULRunner:

```
wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/10.0/runtimes/xulrunner-10.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
tar xjvf xulrunner-10.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo cp -R ./xulrunner/ /usr/lib/
```

If you are using 32bit version of Linux, download and unpack the 32bit version of XULRunner:

```
wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/10.0/runtimes/xulrunner-10.0.en-US.linux-i686.tar.bz2
tar xjvf xulrunner-10.0.en-US.linux-i686.tar.bz2
sudo cp -R ./xulrunner/ /usr/lib/
```

---

Aleksandr Zhuikov has an another workaround in his blog:
http://aleksz-programming.blogspot.com/2013/03/eclipse-and-webkit-on-ubuntu-64.html

He provides a modified version of libwebkitgtk package which fixes this problem.
Unfortunately his package is no longer installable via normal way on updated systems today, as it breaks other libraries such as "libjavascriptcoregtk".

It is, however, possible to unpack his package manually and replace existing webkit library directly:

```
dpkg -x libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_1.10.0-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ./
sudo cp ./usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0.17.3 /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0.17.3
sudo ln -f -s /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0.17.3 /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0
```

Obviously this can break other Webkit-based applications in future, so let's hope Eclipse fixes this problem before more things break.

Answer (score 1):

Since Eclipse Kepler (4.3), you can tell SWT to load `libwebkitgtk-3.0` by defining the `SWT_GTK3` environment variable

```
export SWT_GTK3=1
```

This will eliminate most causes of crash that were experienced with 'libwebkitgtk-1.0' versions.

In 4.3 SWT_GTK3 can take any value (only test is on existence). In 4.4 it is possible that the only meaningful value might be "1". (See [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=423220) for additional detail).

Comment: For eclipse 4.4 I already have 3.0 by default.
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0+0x42682e]  webkitWebViewRegisterForIconNotification+0xbe

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem can still (or again) happen even with libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0 (not 3.0 or 1.0) in Eclipse 4.7 & 4.8 (Photon) e.g. on Fedora 26, and that (new) problem seems to be worked on in [Eclipse Bug 522733](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522733).