# A fatal error has been detected by jre while developing android application

Tags: android, eclipse, swt

I am using eclipse on ubuntu 12.04 and developing an android app, when i start my eclipse and start working, it works but suddenly eclipse crashes and a log file is created on the desktop named hs_err_pid8333.log . I am facing this problem since two days. I have also checked jre for that.. But still eclipse crashes frequently.

```
My hs_err_pid8333.log file :

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f20febde820, pid=8333, tid=139782262421248
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0+0x47d820]  webkit_dom_html_video_element_get_webkit_dropped_frame_count+0x9a00
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f2190008000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=8334, stack(0x00007f219808f000,0x00007f2198190000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007f21901fa0b0, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x00007f21040fc400
RSP=0x00007f219818d508, RBP=0x00007f21040fc400, RSI=0x00007f21909d6a20, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x00007f219100c1b0, R9 =0x00007f21909d6a20, R10=0x0000000000000000, 
Instructions: (pc=0x00007f20febde820)
0x00007f20febde800:   74 0e 48 89 c7 48 83 c4 08 e9 62 13 f1 ff 66 90
0x00007f20febde810:   31 c0 48 83 c4 08 c3 90 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00
0x00007f20febde820:   48 8b 07 53 48 89 fb ff 90 68 05 00 00 48 8d 43
0x00007f20febde830:   10 5b c3 90 66 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007f21901fa0b0 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007f21040fc400 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f219818d508 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f2190008000
RBP=0x00007f21040fc400 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00007f21909d6a20 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f219100c1b0 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007f21909d6a20 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000000000000a is an unknown value
R12=0x00007f21901fb310 is an unknown value
R13=0x00007f2190ab1190 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f217ce2ec60: <offset 0x13c60> in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libatk-bridge.so at 0x00007f217ce1b000


Stack: [0x00007f219808f000,0x00007f2198190000],  sp=0x00007f219818d508,  free space=1017k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0+0x47d820]  webkit_dom_html_video_element_get_webkit_dropped_frame_count+0x9a00

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(JZ)Z+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(JZ)Z+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+36
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run()V+638
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+236
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+108
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+119
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f210c08f800 JavaThread "Recommenders-Bus-Thread-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8418, stack(0x00007f20b4057000,0x00007f20b4158000)]
  0x00007f2190a35000 JavaThread "Recommenders-Timeout-Manager" [_thread_8c317000] [id=8346]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 139008K, used 74149K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 103296K, 37% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f7aeefe0,0x00000000fba40000)
  from space 35712K, 99% used [0x00000000fba40000,0x00000000fdd1a608,0x00000000fdd20000)
  to   space 35712K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd20000,0x00000000fdd20000,0x0000000100000000)
 PSOldGen        total 88448K, used 60342K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5660000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 88448K, 68% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e3aeda50,0x00000000e5660000)
 PSPermGen       total 195072K, used 124575K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000dbe80000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 195072K, 63% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d79a7ef0,0x00000000dbe80000)

Code Cache  [0x00007f218d000000, 0x00007f218d690000, 0x00007f2190000000)
 total_blobs=2198 nmethods=1443 adapters=706 free_code_cache=44001728 largest_free_block=176128

Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00409000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 3937191                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
00608000-00609000 r--p 00008000 08:06 3937191                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/                 /usr/lib/jvm/java-

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)
uname:Linux 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 16:19:23 UTC 2013 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.15 NPTL 2.15 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 28884, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:1.50 1.10 1.72

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        3715928 kB
MemFree:          175732 kB
Buffers:           44580 kB
Cached:          1696892 kB
SwapCached:          452 kB
Active:          1997152 kB
Inactive:        1356780 kB
Active(anon):    1355692 kB
Inactive(anon):   735796 kB
Active(file):     641460 kB
Inactive(file):   620984 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       5253116 kB
SwapFree:        5243216 kB
Dirty:               252 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1612076 kB
Mapped:           178004 kB
Shmem:            479020 kB
Slab:              95228 kB
SReclaimable:      66400 kB
SUnreclaim:        28828 kB
KernelStack:        4048 kB
PageTables:        30824 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     7111080 kB
Committed_AS:    4564172 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      414332 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359315420 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       73728 kB
DirectMap2M:     3784704 kB


CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 37 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 3715928k(175732k free), swap 5253116k(5243216k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_27-b27), built on Nov 16 2013 15:13:05 by "buildd" with gcc 4.6.3

time: Wed Dec 18 13:25:37 2013
elapsed time: 55 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend installing the real **Java from Oracle**. There is an Ubuntu repository available that let's you easily install Oracle Java on any Ubuntu distribution.

**Install Oracle Java 7 in Ubuntu or Linux Mint via PPA**
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse Kepler (4.3), you can tell SWT to load `libwebkitgtk-3.0` by defining the `SWT_GTK3` environment variable

```
export SWT_GTK3=1
```

This will eliminate most causes of crash that were experienced with 'libwebkitgtk-1.0' versions.

In 4.3 SWT_GTK3 can take any value (only test is on existence). In 4.4 it is possible that the only meaningful value might be "1". (See [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=423220) for additional detail).

Comment: Instead of copy/pasting your answer from [Eclipse closing all hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137348/eclipse-closing-all-hours/20659294#20659294), you should flag this question as a duplicate of the one you originally answered (if it really is one). If it is not a duplicate, than your answer is invalid.

Comment: @newfurniturey. Thanks for your insights. You seem to be reasoning on the assumption that one solution can only fix one problem.  Is that so?

Comment: No, however, if one solution is the same for multiple questions than those questions *have* to be similar. In reviewing both questions for similarity and comparing their solutions, it is quite obvious that both this question and the one I previously linked are caused by the same issue - ergo this is a duplicate question (if you mark this question as duplicate, it will contain a link to the other).